# Meaning of this expectation equation?

Tags: probability, algorithms, stochastic-processes, expected-value

I was actually looking at this [problem](http://math.mit.edu/~jsoto/localpapers/spams2010.pdf) on slide 12. I will write it here briefly:

**Problem:**

Unknown number of people arriving in a fixed time period and my goal is to maximize my probability of picking the best candidate

**Assumptions:**

- Assume people arrive in interval [0,1] independently
- May assume also uniformly
- Can NOT beat probability $\frac{1}{e}$ to win.

**Proof:**

Fix a wall at time $T$ and select the best candidate after $T$. Let $t$ be the time at which the best candidate arrives, then:

$Prob(Win) \geq E_{t}[1_{\{t>T\}}\frac{T}{t}] = \int_{T}^{1}\frac{T}{t}dt = -T~ln~T$

This is optimum at $T=\frac{1}{e}$ with a $Prob(Win) = \frac{1}{e} = 36.7\%$

I have a few questions. Can someone please explain how to interpret the expectation equation? In addition, what is the significance of the statement "*Assume people arrive in interval $[0,1]$ independently.*"? Does it mean that I cannot consider some other time interval, say $[0, \alpha]$ or do I need to just multiply $\alpha$ by $\frac{1}{e}$ to get the actual time of making the decision?

I am just trying to figure out what I should do to convert this into an actual real-world implementation. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than "Fix a wall at time $T$ and select the best candidate after $T$", I think you may be using "Fix a wall at time $T$ and select the first candidate to arrive at or after $T$ who is better than all those arriving before time $T$".  This is a continuous version of the [secretary problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_problem).

$E_{t}[1_{\{t>T\}}\frac{T}{t}]$ can be interpreted in two parts: $1_{\{t>T\}}$ is an indicator that the best candidate arrives at or after time $T$, i.e. you have not already rejected the best overall candidate; $\frac{T}{t}$ is the probability that the best candidate to arrive strictly before time $t$ arrives before time $T$, i.e. that you have not selected a candidate who is not the best overall. The expectation of the indicator of an event is the probability of that event.

The interval $[0,1]$ is simply the time during which you see the candidates.  You can scale this to other units, so if you are looking at time $[0,\alpha]$ then your $T=\frac{1}{e}$ will be scaled to $\frac{\alpha}{e}$.

Comment: This is exactly the secretary problem. At HCSSiM, the lore was that this was first presented in a talk titled 'sex and the single statistician.'